# C++ const correctness / missing const constructor for class supporting both const and non-const instances

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I have several linked classes like in the following example where I want them to support both non-const and const instances (as in function `x`):

```
#include <vector>

class Original;

class View
{
public:
    View(Original *that) : m(that) {}
    Original * m;
};

class Original
{
public:
    auto columns() {return View(this);}
    //~ const auto columns() const {return View(this);} // comment #1
    std::vector<int> m;
};

void x()
{
    Original o1;
    const Original o2;
    //~ o2.columns(); // comment #2
}
```

I compile it with `g++ -std=gnu++17 -c const.cpp` and get the following results:

case 1: just as above: compiles just fine (which puzzles me already in the light that in case 2 below I just add a call, and it will fail...)

case 2: uncomment #2, and we get...

```
const.cpp: In function 'void x()':
const.cpp:24:13: error: passing 'const Original' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  o2.columns(); // comment #2
             ^
const.cpp:15:7: note:   in call to 'auto Original::columns()'
  auto columns() {return View(this);}
       ^~~~~~~
```

case 3: in addition, uncomment #1; which yields...

```
const.cpp: In member function 'const auto Original::columns() const':
const.cpp:16:46: error: invalid conversion from 'const Original*' to 'Original*' [-fpermissive]
  const auto columns() const {return View(this);} // comment #1
                                              ^
const.cpp:8:2: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'View::View(Original*)'
  View(Original *that) : m(that) {}
  ^~~~
```

To me it looks like I need to have a constructor for creating a const object, which isn't available in C++.
So I tried making `View` a template class, for supporting both const and non-const member `m`. But I didn't get it running right away and it feels rather ugly anyway.

Anybody any hints? Thanks a lot already!

Comment: Case 2 and case 3 are distinct errors, and questions tend to be more useful to others when they focus on one error at a time. Do you have a better reason for combining these questions than the fact that both are derived from the same program?

Comment: shouldn't there no leading ~ in case uncommented

Comment: @JaMiT: I just wanted to give a hint on what I already tried; the errors are dependent on each other

Comment: @wolfgang What makes you think the errors are dependent on each other? They are not. What happens if you uncomment #1 but not #2? You still get the "case 3" error! That strongly suggests independence.

Comment: sorry, I just realized that the original question missed the crucial part that I want the class to support **both** const and non-const usage, like in function `x`. I updated the question now...

Comment: Maybe look into how `std::span` and `std::string_view` are implemented

Answer (score 0):

Your `View` constructor takes an `Original` pointer, but you're trying to pass it a pointer to a `const Original`! You need the constructor (and the member variable) to reflect that:

```
class View
{
public:
    View(const Original *that) : m(that) {}
    const Original * m;
};
```

See it run here: https://ideone.com/nEgFxD

However if you're okay with taking the hit for making deep copies, even better would be to avoid the pointer business altogether:

```
//Declare Original out so View can use its copy/move constructor
class Original
{
public:
    auto columns();
    const auto columns() const;
    std::vector<int> m;
};

//Full declaration/implementation of View
class View
{
public:
    View(const Original &that) : m(that) { }
    Original m;
};

//Now that View's constructors are defined, implement these Original funcs
auto Original::columns() {return View(*this);}
const auto Original::columns() const {return View(*this);} // comment #1

int main()
{
    Original o1;
    const Original o2;
    o2.columns(); // comment #2
}
```

See it run here: https://ideone.com/HnpQ38

Comment: For your first proposal I probably oversimplified my example, since I also need the case where `m` is not const. For your second one - that looks good, but isn't the copy of `Original.m` expensive?

Comment: Ahh then I'd suggest making a deep copy instead of a shallow one @wolf. Do you want me to update my answer with an example of that?

Comment: @wolf in regards to the second example, yes it will be somewhat expensive, but if you must have a non-const `Original`, your only way to (legally) get that from a const `Original` is going to be to make a copy.

Comment: if everything else fails, having a template `View` for both const and non-const `m` should be able to do without a copy

Comment: It should...but if you're going to be making the same calls regardless of whether you have a const pointer or non-const pointer, why can't everything just be const? @wolf

Comment: well, `View` would get some modifying methods as well (they may only be called in the non-const case, though).

Comment: Then what would you do in the Template if you're given a const `Original` @wolf? Maybe you could elaborate on what the actual use case is here? What is the semantic purpose of `View`? Why does it need an `Original` pointer and what does it do with it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with today, but based on templates (which I think is rather ugly); it supports both the const and the non-const usage (as in function `x`):

```
#include <vector>

class Original;

template<class T>
class View
{
public:
    View(T *that) : m(that) {}
    T * m;
};

class Original
{
public:
    auto columns() {return View(this);}
    const auto columns() const {return View(this);}
    std::vector<int> m;
};

void x()
{
    Original o1;
    const Original o2;
    o2.columns();
}
```